# vb.net main will not allow private variables to be set

Tags: vb.net, variables, scope, program-entry-point

I have the following code - I want to preset / initialize some variables that are in subroutines before I start. (Specifically, I will read a control file and pre-load some variables, like the starting folder search path).  How do I do this?

Public Class Form1

```
<STAThread()> _
Shared Sub Main()
    Dim mainWindow As Form1 = New Form1()
    MessageBox.Show("Hello! I'm exectuing!")


    ' This next line generates an error.
    ' I don't know how to set this variable in Main. 
    ' How do I set up variables, perhaps from a control file ?
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\mypath"

    Application.Run(mainWindow)

End Sub
Private Sub FindButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FindButton.Click

    ' Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a Cursor.
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    ' Filter by All Files
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*"

    openFileDialog1.Title = "Process a File"


    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists Then
            If openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists Then
                ' do stuff with the file here 

        Else
            StatusLabel.Text = "Path does not exist"
        End If
    Else
        StatusLabel.Text = "openFileDialog1.ShowDialog error"
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 2):

Because in VB 'Shared' is analogous to 'static' in C#.  And you're trying to make a static reference to an instance of an object.

That is `openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\mypath"` is trying to reference the openFileDialog1 object instance.  Move that line to Form1's constructor (or possibly someother more appropriate event, oninit or something i'm not familiar with winforms), and it should accomplish the same thing.

[MSDN VB Shared Sope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)